# Prevent retriggering mouseenter on parent div when child hidden

Tags: angular, mouseevent, mouseenter

I have a parent div where a user's mouse enters, then they click a child input to hide it (mousedown).

Is it possible to prevent triggering another mousenter on the parent div when the child is hidden?

For example, the sequence currently becomes:

```
onMouseEnter Blue Container
input mouseEnter
input hidden
onMouseEnter Blue Container
```

I want to prevent the last "onMouseEnter Blue Container" from being triggered (i.e., parent mouseEnter should not trigger again).

Stackblitz is here:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mouseenter-dquf3y

Below is my component:

```
<div [ngClass]="class" #target
    (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter($event)"
    (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave($event)">
    <input (mouseenter)="this.log('input mouseEnter')" 
           type="checkbox" (click)="doHide()" *ngIf="!hide"/>
</div>
```

Below is my TS:

```
onMouseEnter($event) {
    this.log('onMouseEnter Blue Container');
    this.isHovering = true;
  }

  onMouseLeave($event) {
    this.log('onMouseLeave');
    this.isHovering = false;
  }

  hide = false;
  doHide() {
    this.hide = !this.hide;
    if (this.hide === true) {
      this.log('input hidden')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the input element with:

```
*ngIf="!hide"
```

you can hide it with:

```
[hidden]="hide"
```

That appears to avoid the triggering of the `mouseenter` event on the parent.

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mouseenter-qsvhdz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) for a demo.